# username password verification with DAO class WITHOUT SCRIPTLETS or java code in .jsp page

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans, jsp-tags

I want to just run a method in a javaBean class (its not a getter or setter method) it takes 2 parameters (username , password) and returns a boolean (after varifing it from the database(seperate DAO class)).

then I want to make a a decision depending on that boolean value to show some text or redirect page. how can i do it.? **do i need JSTL or jsp:action (useBean and set/get property) tag or  would be enough?**

**WITHOUT SCRIPTLETS or java code in .jsp page. niether any framworks like struts or spring**
any practical code?

index.jsp

```
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Open-Pages</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form method="post" action="/open-pages/comments.jsp">
        User Name: <input type="text" name="userName">
        <br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        <input type="reset" value="reset">
      </form>
      </body>
  </html>
```

comments.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
//         out.println(request.getParameter("userName"));
//         out.println(request.getParameter("userName"));
    %>

    <jsp:useBean id="verifyUser" class="entry.UserBean" scope="page" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="verifyUser" property="userName" param="userName" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="verifyUser" property="password" param="password" />

    <jsp:getProperty name="verifyUser" property="userName" />
    <jsp:getProperty name="verifyUser" property="password" />


    </body>
</html>
```

UserBean.java

```
      /*
      * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
      * and open the template in the editor.
      */
      package entry;

      import java.io.Serializable;


      /**
      *
      * @author user1
      */
      public class UserBean implements Serializable{
      private String userName;
      private String password;
      private boolean validUser;

      /**
      * @return the userName
      */
      public String getUserName() {
          return userName;
      }

      /**
      * @param userName the userName to set
      */
      public void setUserName(String userName) {
          this.userName = userName;
      }

      /**
      * @return the password
      */
      public String getPassword() {
          return password;
      }

      /**
      * @param password the password to set
      */
      public void setPassword(String password) {
          this.password = password;
      }




      public boolean getValidUser(String user, String password) {
          if(entry.userAuthDAO.verifyUserPass(user,password)){
        return true;
        }else {
        return false;
        }
      }


      public void setValidUser(boolean validUser) {
          this.validUser = validUser;
      }
      }
```

UserAuthDAO

```
      package entry;


      import entry.Constants;
      import java.sql.Connection;
      import java.sql.DriverManager;
      import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
      import java.sql.ResultSet;
      import java.sql.SQLException;
      import java.util.logging.Level;
      import java.util.logging.Logger;

      /*
      * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
      * and open the template in the editor.
      */

      /**
      *
      * @author user1
      */
      public class userAuthDAO {

      static String authUser = "select userName, password "
              + "from users "
              + "where userName = ? and password = ?";
      public static boolean verifyUserPass(String userName, String password){


          try {
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Constants.DBHost, userName, password);
          PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(authUser);

          pStmt.setString(1,userName);
          pStmt.setString(2, password);

          ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
          String rsUserName = null;
          String rsPassword = null;
          if(rs.next()){
              rsUserName = rs.getString("userName");
              rsPassword =  rs.getString("password");    
          }

          con.close();

          if (rsUserName.equals(userName) && rsPassword.equals(password)){
              return true;
          }



        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(userAuthDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        return false; 
      }

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that in a JSP. That's not what JSPs are for. They're view components, and should be used to generate HTML markup.

Do that from a servlet, or an action of your preferred MVC framework. Once the servlet or action has the result, then dispatch to a JSP or redirect.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I dont want to use a framwork like spring or struts. secondly how do you want me to do that in a servlet and "link" that to the jsp? thirdly, dont I need jstl or beans or exp language?

Comment: `request.getRequestDispatcher("/the/jsp/to/display.jsp").forward(request, response);`. As simple as that. Why don't you want to use an MVC framework? Yes, using the JSTL and the EL is fine, but that doesn't change the fact that JSPs are view components, and shouldn't be used to execute business or security logic.

Comment: hm.. can you alter a bit of comments.jsp ? how do i link the servlet working with the .jsp

Comment: The comments.jsp should display comments. It should not do anything regarding the password verification. See http://www.jcorporate.com/expresso/doc/edg/edg_WhatIsMVC.html for an explanation of the MVC pattern. The request should go to a servlet first (i.e. the form in the index.jsp should be submitted to a servlet, and not to the comments.jsp). The servlet will check the password. Once the password is checked, it will get the comments in the database, store them in a request attribute, and forward to the comments JSP, which will iterate through the comments and display them.

Comment: thanks again.hm.. so theres would be a servlet in the middle of index.jsp and comments.jsp . and we should not use c:if  or forEach or any other jstl or EL ? (I know mvc 1,2 but dont know how to code practically) if I understood the above? i can start... :)

Comment: Of course you would use the JSTL and the EL. For example, to iterate through the comment list and display the author and text of each comment. In short, to generate the HTML page sent to the browser.

Comment: iam going to mark this answer as accepted and making it as useful +1 . I would really appreciate if you tell me what do you think that what kind of tags in jstl or EL should not be used?

Comment: Avoid the sql and xml libraries completely. The other libraries are fine, except c:redirect, c:catch, and the fmt:parseXxx tags. But if you respect the MVC pattern you'll naturally use the tags that are useful to generate HTML.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20478/discussion-between-masood-and-jb-nizet)